# Javascript cross browser scripting

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

I have a tiny function I use to only allow numeric input. It works great in IE, but I cannot get it to work in FireFox or Chrome. I have this js file loaded in my script tag of my HTML page.

```
var numberOnly = function(evt) { 

  var theEvent = evt || window.event; 
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which; 
  key = String.fromCharCode( key ); 
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./; 
  if( !regex.test(key) ) { 
    theEvent.returnValue = false; 

 } 
}; 

var wireElemToEvent = function(elemId, event, func){

var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
if (typeof window.event !== 'undefined') {
    elem.attachEvent("on" + event, func);
} else {
    elem.addEventListener(event, func, true);
}
};



var wireEvents = function(){

wireElemToEvent("tbxQuantity", "keypress", numberOnly);
wireElemToEvent("tbxPhone", "keypress", numberOnly);
wireElemToEvent("tbxZip", "keypress", numberOnly);


};

window.onload = wireEvents;
```

Chrome tells me

> file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/xxx/Desktop/numbersonly/res/js/numbersonly.js:17Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLInputElement> has no method 'attachEvent'

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `wireElemToEvent` You may want to check that `elem` is not null after you initialize it. Also, it would be better to check the existence of `elem.attachEvent` and `elem.addEventListener` rather than whether `window.event` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function I use to attach events cross browser:

```
 function eventListen( t, fn, o ) {
  o = o || window;
  var e = t+fn;
  if ( o.attachEvent ) {
   o['e'+e] = fn;
   o[e] = function(){
    o['e'+e]( window.event );
   };
   o.attachEvent( 'on'+t, o[e] );
  }else{
   o.addEventListener( t, fn, false );
  }
 }
```

And to use it:

```
eventListen('message', function(e){
 var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and, because I am a novice, was looking around for a day for a solution.
Apparently (typeof window.event !== 'undefined') doesn't stop Safari/Chrome from getting in that if statement. So it actually initializes the attachEvent and doesn't know what to do with it.

Solution:

```
var wireElemToEvent = function(elemId, event, func){

var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
if (elem.attachEvent) {
    elem.attachEvent("on" + event, func);
} 
else { // if (elem.addEventListener) interchangeably
    elem.addEventListener(event, func, true);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One good way to make cross-browser scripting easier is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  Plus, there's no reason to reinvent the wheel.  Why not try this jQuery plugin: [jQuery » numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/)

Comment: +1. Cross browser support will always lead back to jQuery :) Sooo much easier.

Comment: I agree 100% and I use and love jQuery, however on this particular project, jQuery is not being used. The customer doesn't want any 3rd party libs.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Does your customer know that jQuery is supported by Microsoft and will ship as part of Visual Studio 2010?  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx

Comment: -1: The answer is not always JQuery. It is extremely easy to attach events in a cross-browser supported way without all the overhead.

Comment: @Joel: You are right, of course.  But using jQuery was merely a suggested alternative.  I see no problem promoting the use of, and raising awareness of, a library that I like.

Comment: @Andy: I like the library too, but is not a good answer to the current question (or at least there are better answers). I'd have upvoted you if you'd given a pure javascript solution AND suggested JQuery.

Comment: @Joel: I often find the overhead (and there is very little) worth the time saved writing and debugging code like this.